# How to draw a 5*5 array and move images on it

Tags: android

I have a project which i'm required to develop Android game that display a 5*5 table and and image for each player which each one of them can move the image in place inside the 5*5 table.

ex:

[image: An example of the game, where each player has 5 stones and he can move them one step each time.]

Note : I need to know the exact coordinates (or anything relative) so i can save the position in array and move the image to that new place (eg : re-draw it on the new position).

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend google some libraries.. something like this? https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid there is a demo video

Comment: Maybe you can show us with paint what you really want? :)

Comment: For animated drag and drop you can look at Google's dynamic listview, and for the game board I'd suggest a GridLayout.  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/devbytes/animation/ListViewDraggingAnimation/src/com/example/android/listviewdragginganimation/DynamicListView.java

Comment: @Wicked161089 i will see and feedback to you. Thanks

Comment: @DaveS i will see and feedback to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a RelativeLayout with 5x5 ImageViews (set to not visible).
And on the images that the user can move to the place, use Drag and Drop.
In onDrag you set the visibility of the image to Gone. 
For all ImageView (5x5 Table), you set the onDragListener.
After that, in the overwritten method OnDrop, you can receive the view that is dropped and can determine which drawable to show.

edit:

Oh well, in this case I would use GridView as said in the comments. And make usage of drag and drop. You don't need to attach a DragListener to every image then. You can simply let the GridView listen to the drop events and determine by the x and y where to drop.

Little example (just as a hint)

```
gameStoneView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(gameStoneView);
            gameStoneView.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, gameStoneView, 0);
            if (dragListener != null) {
                dragListener.onDragStart();
            }
            break;
        default:
            LOG.v("Motion event reorderIcon: DEFAULT - not action down");
    }
    return true;
}
```

});

```
        gridView.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                        currentY = event.getY();
                        currentX = event.getX();
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                        final Point position = getPositionOfItem(currentX, currentY);
                        dropItemAt(position);
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                        //BORDER DRAGEVENT: ACTION_DRAG_EXITED
                        viewDraggedOutSide = true;
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                        //BORDER DRAGEVENT: ACTION_DRAG_ENDED
                        if (viewDraggedOutSideList) {
                            reinsertDraggedItem();
                            update();
                        }
                        viewDraggedOutSideList = false;
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Pretty cool, Can you please take a look at the question again because i edited it with more details and uploaded a photo.